# Looking for a GLPI like software

Tags: web

I'm looking for a GLPI like software. GLPI is really focused on IT devices management.
I need something more general that would let me define my own devices and kits.
I'm looking for a web based solution, do you have recommendations?

It should handle device reservation, inventory (single pieces and kits), physical location of devices (where are they stored).

Thanks and regards,

Comment: I'm interested if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already familiar with RT (http://www.bestpractical.com/rt), there might be a little bit of a learning curve, but by itself it can definitely function as a general item accounting system. There is also an addon specifically for inventory type functions called AssetTracker (http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/AssetTracker).

I've used RT to handle inventory, creating queues for specific type of equipment and then adding appropriate custom fields, etc. As far as reservation goes, that could be handled by the RT approval mechanism, or perhaps moving equipment tickets into specific queues based upon whom they are reserved to, etc.